# Как сделать возможность ввода во время цикла в C#?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно, чтобы во время цикла был доступен ввод от пользователя, дабы ввести код деактивации. Не понимаю, как сделать.

Мой код:

```cs
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("Введите код для активации бомбы:");
string bombCode = Console.ReadLine();
if (Convert.ToInt32(bombCode) == 30032005)
{
    Console.WriteLine("До взрыва осталось 45 секунд. Чтобы разминировать бомбу - введите код деактивации.");
    for (int bombtimer = 45; bombtimer >= 0; bombtimer--) 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"До взрыва осталось {bombtimer} секунд.");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Неверный код для активации бомбы!");
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, первая регистрация на этом форуме) Как и вопрос.

Comment: Это не совсем форум, а база знаний. Сейчас что-нибудь придумаем.

Comment: Поток отдельный нужен. Или Task.

Comment: @aepot Ну так что там?

Comment: Он пытался ответить. Но взорвался...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov :D

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov и не такой код мы здесь разминировали, вам ли не знать. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Немного асинхронного и объектно-ориентированного программирования, и вот что получилось.

Создадим класс бомбы, он будет отвечать за разблокировку и отсчет оставшегося времени.

```cs
public class Bomb
{
    private TimeSpan _second = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    private int _code;
    private TimeSpan _time;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private int _left;
    private int _top;

    public bool Armed => _cts != null;

    public Bomb(int code, TimeSpan time)
    {
        _code = code;
        _time = time;
        Console.Write("Осталось: ");
        _top = Console.CursorTop;
        _left = Console.CursorLeft;
        Console.WriteLine(_time.ToString("mm\\:ss"));
    }

    public async void Arm()
    {
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            await RunTimer(_cts.Token);
        }
        _cts = null;
    }

    public void Disarm(int code)
    {
        if (_cts == null)
            return;

        if (code == _code)
            _cts?.Cancel();
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Неверный код");
    }

    private async Task RunTimer(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            while (_time >= TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                _time -= _second;
                await Task.Delay(1000, token);
                int tmpLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                int tmpTop = Console.CursorTop;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(_left, _top);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(_time.ToString("mm\\:ss"));
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(tmpLeft, tmpTop);
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Бах!");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) 
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Обезврежено.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и давайте играть с этим классом

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Активация.");
        int code;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Введите код: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadPassword(), out code) || code <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Неподходящий код, попробуйте еще раз.");
            }
        }
        while (code <= 0);

        int seconds;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Введите время в секундах: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out seconds) || seconds <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Неподходящее время, попробуйте еще раз.");
            }
        }
        while (seconds <= 0);

        Bomb bomb = new Bomb(code, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для активации...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        bomb.Arm();
        while (bomb.Armed)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите код: ");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out code) && code > 0)
                bomb.Disarm(code);
            else
            if (bomb.Armed)
                Console.WriteLine("Неподходящий код, попробуйте еще раз.");
        }
    }

    private static string ReadPassword()
    {
        string password = string.Empty;
        ConsoleKey key;
        do
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            key = keyInfo.Key;

            if (key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && password.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\b \b");
                password = password[0..^1];
            }
            else if (!char.IsControl(keyInfo.KeyChar))
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                password += keyInfo.KeyChar;
            }
        } while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.WriteLine();
        return password;
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Активация.
Введите код: ****
Введите время в секундах: 120
Осталось: 01:52
Нажмите любую клавишу для активации...
Введите код: 123
Неверный код
Введите код: 1234
Обезврежено.
```

В качестве домашнего задания, разберитесь с этим кодом. Очень важно понять, как это работает. Это наверняка еще можно доработать. Например, вводить долго коды, таймер уезжает вверх и консоль начинает дергаться, чтобы отрисовать время. Но это можно исправить вводя код на одном и том же месте консоли, аналогично как выводится время в одном и том же месте.

Comment: Спасибо большое <3