# Вывод текста в ту же часть консоли

Tags: c#

для практики хочу написать таймер в консоли и пока не понимаю как сделать чтоб не начинался с новой строки а менял само число на большее! пожалуйста подскажите в какую часть документаций нужно лезть я не прошу готовое решение!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1240063/373567

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, надо поставить зеленую галочку слева от наиболее полезного ответа. Так же зайдите к себе в профиль, там есть ответы на ваши прошлые вопросы, ни одного из которых вы не приняли.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В эту: [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Console_SetCursorPosition_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

Как найти: вы же наверное знаете, что у класса Console есть какие-то методы типа Write и WriteLine - ну и посмотрите рядом в документации, какие ещё есть. Либо обычно ещё проще делают: пишут Console, ставят точку и смотрят какие методы в подсказках автокомплита имеются.

Альтернативно, если у вас на экране только эта строка с таймером и вы можете позволить себе убрать всё на экране и заново написать значение таймера - рядом есть [Console.Clear](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.clear?view=net-5.0), можете с ним поэкспериментировать.

Answer (score 4):

Для возврата курсора в начало строки можно использовать `\r`:

```
Console.Write("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}\r", h, m, s)
```