# C# async вывод последовательности чисел

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

Как мне написать свой асинхронный метод, который, например, выводит на экран последовательность чисел? (Предполагается, что Console.WriteLine будет блокировать этот поток, он же все равно работает быстро). То есть я хочу, например, создать 2 таски, которые будут по очереди выводить по числу в консоль. При помощи генераторов я представляю, как решить эту задачу, а как при помощи асинхронного кода?

Comment: Для асинхронной работы нужна асинхронная задача. Вывод в консоль синхронный и выкидывать его в поток - дороже по времени, чем отправить вывод напрямую. То есть, мне не до конца понятно, что вам нужно. Теоретически предположу, что вам стоит призучать шаблон проектирования Producer/Consumer и реализующие его классы типа `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection` и `System.Threading.Channels.Channel`. Ну и всякие трюки с многопоточкой типа [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567).

Comment: Мне это нужно для того, чтобы поучиться работать с асинхронными задачами, не так важно, насколько эффективно или неэффективно мое решение для этой конкретной задачи, важно понять, как мне писать асинхронный код

Comment: А что его учиться писать, писать его просто, ради этого `async/await` и придумали. Для того чтобы пошло дело, надо понять - зачем придумали. Вот тогда станет ясно, какие задачи с помощью этого подхода надо решать. Заворачивать в поток синхронную операцию много ума не требуется. [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). [Вот еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1326718/373567).

Comment: Асинхронный вывод с помощью реактивного подхода(System.Reactive): https://dotnetfiddle.net/fFuRGp

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение, которое мне было нужно. Инструкция **await** внутри асинхронного метода заставляет выходить обратно в планировщик, пока действие не закончено. Мне был интересен метод, который заставляет выходить в планировщик безусловно, им оказался **Task.Yield()**. В итоге решение этой задачи выглядит примерно так:

```
static async Task Out(int n, int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}

static async Task MyOut()
{
    var t1 = Out(10, 1);
    var t2 = Out(10, 2);
    var tasks = new List<Task> { t1, t2 };
    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var ready = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(ready);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started");
    var task = MyOut();
    task.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

В результате вывод будет примерно такой:


*Started

1

2

1

2

1

2

2

2

2

2

2

2

2

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

Finished*


Вызов методов происходит не прямо друг за другом, я предполагаю, что есть какое-то минимальное ограничение в тиках на выполнение кусочка асинхронной задачи, но могу ошибаться. Поправьте меня, если я неправ.