# Для чего нужен \b в C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Что делает символ '\b' в C#?

Единственное использование которое я нашёл, это он может в одной строчке изменять символы без `Console.Clear()`:

```
 static void UpdateText(string text)
        {
            int commonPrefixLength = 0;
            int commonLength = Math.Min(currentText.Length, text.Length);
            while (commonPrefixLength < commonLength && text[commonPrefixLength] == currentText[commonPrefixLength])
            {
                commonPrefixLength++;
            }

            
            StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            outputBuilder.Append('\b', currentText.Length - commonPrefixLength);

            outputBuilder.Append(text.Substring(commonPrefixLength));

           
            int overlapCount = currentText.Length - text.Length;
            if (overlapCount > 0)
            {
                outputBuilder.Append(' ', overlapCount);
                outputBuilder.Append('\b', overlapCount);
            }

            Console.Write(outputBuilder);
            currentText = text;
        }
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B BACKSPACE

Comment: Вот практический пример применения `\b` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1240063/373567 - смотрите в коде на метод `ReadPassword`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный символ обозначает команду backspace и возвращает каретку на один символ назад, что позволяет перетереть последний символ строки.

Например, `Console.WriteLine("1234\b")` вернёт 1234, а `Console.WriteLine("1234\b56")` вернёт уже 12356