# Стирание последнего напечатанного символа в консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

Как реализовать стирание символа в консоли в данном методе? В данный момент при нажатии BackSpace сдвигается курсор, но не пропадает уже введенный символ из консоли

```
public string InputString(string mes, string escapeStr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mes);
            Console.CursorVisible = true;
            StringBuilder buffer = new();
            ConsoleKeyInfo ski = Console.ReadKey(true);
            while (ski.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape && ski.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.Write(ski.KeyChar);
                buffer.Append(ski.KeyChar);
                ski = Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            if (ski.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                return buffer.ToString();
            }
            return escapeStr;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backspace + Space + Backspace

```
if (ski.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
{
    Console.Write("\b \b");
    buffer.Length--;
}
```

[Другой пример реализации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1240063/373567), см. метод `ReadPassword`, обратите внимание на проверку `char.IsControl`.