# C# объясните пж как это работает. ConsoleKey keywoard = Console. ReadKey(). Key;

Tags: c#, консоль, enum

Изучаю только. До этого пользовался `int x = x.Parse(Console. Readline())`. Тут все понятно было. Строка считывается с консоли, конвертируется в int и присваивается.

```
ConsoleKey keywoard = Console.Readkey().Key;
```

`ConsoleKey` - получается тип данных `enum`, это константы там хранятся значения клавиатуры. Для доступа к ним создаётся keywoard(любое название)Пытаюсь разобратся(

`Console.Readkey().Key` - получается значение считывается с консоли, а что `.Key` делает после скобок?

Простите возможно за бред, сам запутался. Можете объяснить каждую ключевое слово и как вообще это строка работает. Благодарю

Comment: Вот, поиграйтесь с примером https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1240063/373567, `Console.ReadKey` возвращает структуру [ConsoleKeyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo), которая содержит не только символ, но и другую полезную информацию. А `Key` это её поле. Вы же не только печатаемые символы можете на клаве нажимать, но и модификаторы, Alt например.

Comment: Т.е после ввода символа в ReadKey(), ReadKey возвращает всю информацию об этом символе(номер символа, нажатую клавишу, значение и тд) и всю эту информацию передаёт в Key.  А Key в свою очередь передаёт эту информацию в переменную типа ConsoleKeyInfo. А дальше создаём переменную consolekey keywoard = info. Key. Т. Е мы из ConsoleKeyInfo извлекаем уже значение, что мы ввели?

Comment: Метод возвращает структуру данных ConsoleKeyInfo, а Key лежит внутри неё, откройте документацию. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/

Answer (score 2):

Ок, давайте по-порядку:

```cs
ConsoleKey keywoard = Console.Readkey().Key;
```

это объявление переменной с присваиванием:

- `ConsoleKey` - это тип переменной, в данном случае `enum`, который содержит кнопку на которую вы нажали.
- `keywoard` - название переменной.
- `Console` - это [класс](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-7.0), который позволяет работать с консолью (ввод-вывод, цвет и т.д.). Если вы не знаете ещё не знаете что такое класс, то пока что можете представить это как некоторый набор переменных и функций объединенные вместе по смыслу.
- `ReadKey()` - это вызов статического метода, который возвращает структуру [ConsoleKeyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo?view=net-7.0). Если вы не знаете ещё не знаете что такое метод, то пока что можете представить это как обычную функцию.
- `.Key` - это свойство, которое назодится в `ConsoleKeyInfo` (получили на предыдущем шаге), вот оно и является [ConsoleKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekey?view=net-7.0). Если вы не знаете ещё не знаете что такое, то пока что можете представить это как переменную, которая хранится в другом классе.

Ваше выращение можно переписать так, возможно понятнее будет:

```cs
ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.Readkey();
ConsoleKey keywoard = info.Key;
```

Просто C# позволяет сразу обращаться к свойству `Key` без сохранения его в промежуточную переменную.

Comment: Получается ConsoleKey содержит в себе список значений клавиш  клавиатуры правильно? А переменная типа ConsoleKey принимает значения, которые допустимы из списка enum(т.е клавиши) чтобы с ними взаимодействовать. (как допустим тип int принимает целочисл значения, а о его, а key преобразует это введенное значение в код клавиши.
Далее код этой клавиши присваивается переменной enum.
Поправте меня если не так понял

Comment: @gachi_muchenik `Получается ConsoleKey содержит в себе список значений клавиш клавиатуры правильно? ` да, список всех допустимых значение можно найти в документации https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekey?view=net-7.0

Comment: @gachi_muchenik `а key преобразует` нет, Key и есть это значение/код, и вы его просто сохраняете в переменную keywoard. `ReadKey()` возвращает информацию о нажатой клавише на клавиатуре - Key, о символе который представляет эта клавиша - KeyChar, и дополнитильные модификаторы - Modifiers (shift ...)

Comment: ConsoleKey keywoard=Console.ReadKey().Key

Т. Е ReadKey() принимает введенное нами значение, и возвращает его уже в виде структуры ConsoleKeyInfo(т.е возвращает все данные об этом значении)Далее мы присваивает значение key(ConsoleKey) (т.е введеного нами символа) переменной keywoard.
А чтобы получить доступ к веденному нами значению мы обращаемся keywoard.Key.

Answer (score 1):

Метод Console.ReadKey() считывает следующий символ ввода консоли и возвращает объект, представляющий нажатую клавишу. Свойство Key этого объекта содержит код клавиши.
Пример

```
Console.WriteLine("Нажмите Y или N чтобы получить результат");
switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.Y:
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Вы нажали Y");
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.N:
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Вы нажали N");
        break;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть мы можем дать выбор нажать Y и выполнить функцию или нажать N и не выполнить функцию. Или же вывести в консоль чтобы пользователь указал цифру какую то, например 5 и считать эту цифру и использовать в приложение для вашей реализации

Comment: А ConsoleKey keywoard    получается просто получает значение из.Key?т.е возвращает код клавиши и присваивает keywoard?

Comment: @gachi_muchenik ```ConsoleKey keywoard = Console.Readkey().Key;```  ```здесь keywoard``` просто получает код клавиши нажатой. Результат нажатой клавиши хранится в переменной keywoard, вы можете обработать это нажатии потом в if или switch или использовать Key как в примере с ответа.

Comment: ConsoleKey keywoard=Console.ReadKey().Key

Т. Е ReadKey() принимает введенное нами значение, и возвращает его уже в виде структуры ConsoleKeyInfo(т.е возвращает все данные об этом значении)Далее мы присваивает значение key(ConsoleKey) (т.е введеного нами символа) переменной keywoard.
А чтобы получить доступ к веденному нами значению мы обращаемся keywoard.Key.